# making exe files that contains pictures and other files

Tags: exe, self-extracting

I have a program that made with c# and it has include more pictures and files.

And how I make an exe that include all of images and files.

Comment: yes .....but i want run app without installing

Comment: Shalitha Suranga are you from LK ?

Comment: Yeah.. Do you want to simply include all images and files used in app to exe as portable app?

Comment: yes.....me too from LK

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Application Resources in visual studio.

1. Right click on Project (Solution Explorer) and Go to Properties
2. Select Resources tab
3. Add what you want (Images, Files, Strings etc.)

You can access them in your code as per below

```
Properties.Resources.<Resource Name>
```

If you added image `img1` to Resources

you can use below code to use it

```
pictureBox1.Image = Properties.Resources.img1;
```